# Export all users for each Distribution Group I own into a csv

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, office365, distribution-list

The below commands will extract all the Distribution groups I own.

> Get-DistributionGroup -ManagedBy James.smith@jesus.com |  Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation

**Question:** How can I expand this so that it it outputs all the members for each group that I own like the examples listed below.

**Group1**

- member 1 - email address
- member 2 - email address

**Group 2**

- member 1 - email address
- member 2 - email address

and so forth!

I checked online and going bat crazy, and help appreciated

Comment: You'll need to use the `Get-DistributionGroupMember` cmdlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **PowerShell #1** solution will dump the **name of the member** and **name of the group** into one csv file and more accurately matches the example logic you provided.

This solution uses `select-object` to add a [calculated property](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/) providing the distribution group name field and value into the csv file. The variable is used to set the group name per the `Get-DistributionGroup` output, but before the `Get-DistributionGroupMember` is run and piped.

### PowerShell #1

```
Get-DistributionGroup -ManagedBy James.smith@jesus.com  | ForEach-Object { 
   $DGName = $_.Name;
   Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_.Name } |  
       Select Name, RecipientType, @{ N='Group Name'; E={$DGName};} |
        Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation;
```

The **PowerShell #2** solution that will dump the **name of the member** into a csv file with the name of the group as the base name of the csv file specified.

This solution works similar to setting the name of the distribution group as a variable as in the first solution, but it will use that to set the base name of the exported csv file to the value. So you'll get one file per group with this solution.

### PowerShell #2

```
Get-DistributionGroup -ManagedBy James.smith@jesus.com | ForEach-Object {
    $DGName = $_.Name;
    Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_.Name } | 
        Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\$DGName.csv" -NoTypeInformation;
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-DistributionGroup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps)
- [Get-DistributionGroupMember](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-distributiongroupmember?view=exchange-ps)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)
- [Calculated_Properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1#select-object)
- [Add a calculated property with Select-Object in PowerShell](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/)
- [Export-Csv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: @SSP Let me know if there is something missing or needed further from the exported data. Getting more data is just a trivial matter and won't take me much time to help you determine logic adjustment should something further be needed there. Just let me know and I am happy to help you get this further solidified if required.

Comment: This is perfect thank you, Solution 1 is perfect, means we can create a power bi report based on 1 export!